# Javascript, POST Received but JSON not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

On the client side, I have the following jQuery code

```
$("#formid").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var posting = $.post("http://localhost:8080",{"test":"testing"});
    posting.done(function(data){
        alert("success");
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("fail");});
});
```

On the server side, I have the following code.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log(request.method);
    request.addListener('data', function(chunk){
        echoString = chunk.toString();
        console.log("got a chunk: ", echoString);
    });
});
server.listen(8080, function(){ 
    console.log("Server listening on: localhost:%s";, 8080); });
```

My problem is that when I submit the form, the server recognizes the message as a POST, but the JSON is not received. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Edits/Additional Info: None of the alerts trigger, the client just hangs. The only thing that prints out to Terminal is POST. If I print the entire request, I see that I correctly get a POST every time, but no JSON data is ever received.

Comment: `response.json(echoString)` ?

Comment: If you could please clarify, what does happen? Are you receiving any errors? Does the console display any "`got a chunk:`" messages? Also, note that `jQuery.ajax()` formats `data` as [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) rather than JSON.

Comment: does `alert('fail')` happen? if so, do you get an error message?

Comment: For the node end, what is printing out in the Terminal where you have those console.logs?

Comment: your http server isnt listening to any port? I hope its a typo while copying your code